# Ng-Repeat Filter Empty string

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have tried to filter blank string item from ng-repeat. But didn't succeeded. Can someone please help me at this.

[JSFiddel Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ovsqf17n/9/)

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="detail in details | filter: filter2 ">
            <p>{{detail.name}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS Code:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.details = [{
        name: 'Bill',
        shortDescription: null
    }, {
        name: 'Sally',
        shortDescription: 'A girl'
    },{
        name: 'Tally',
        shortDescription: ''
    }];
}

function filter2(detail){
    if (item.shortDescription.length == 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
/*
Expected Result

Bill
Sally
*/
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not seem to work...

Answer (score 2):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="detail in details" ng-if="detail.shortDescription">
            <p>{{detail.name}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86ytqwLt/)

Comment: Thanks for Replying. Actually I wanted only One item from them.